# How do you fill a column with a value conditional on another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want a column `x` to be filled with the value of `cyl` when `mpg` is at its lowest.

In base R I could write something like

```
mtcars$x = mtcars[min(mtcars$mpg), "cyl"]
```

How would I write something like this using `dplyr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want

```
mtcars %>% mutate(x = cyl[which.min(mpg)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of mutate and ifelse you will be able to achieve the desired effect!

When mpg is not at its lowest, x's value will be `NA`

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars%>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(mpg == min(mpg), cyl, NA))
```

Comment: sorry, I want the whole column to be filled with `cyl` value

Comment: Ah, I see in that case use Allan Cameron's answer!